# Is there a KSP-to-PKCS#11-Bridge?

Tags: windows, cryptography

We are using a lot of cryptographic operations via the Windows CNG (which in turn uses a KSP to obtain keys for the cryptographic algorithms it executes). Most HSM vendors provide a KSP implementation, but many more only provide a PKCS#11 interface. Is there a generic KSP-to-PKCS#11 bridge/adapter out there?